# Como converter json para objeto e colocar em um system.out.println?

Tags: java, json, java-8

Tenho o seguinte código que retornar um JSON:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import classes_json.JSONObject;

 class Connection {

     private String resultado;
     private JSONObject js_object;
     private  JSONObject obj_kappauni1;



void conectar() throws IOException {

    final String ENDERECO = "http://dwarfpool.com/eth/api?wallet=0940f5fAEF2bba7e1e6288E4bc4E9c75ee334b97";
    //Passo por parametro o endereco no qual deve pegar o json
    URL url = new URL(ENDERECO);
    //Abro conexão usando a url do json, assim vai ser conectado
    URLConnection conexao = url.openConnection();
    //Ler valores da api
    InputStreamReader inStreamread = new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream());
    //Guardar valores api em buffer
    BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(inStreamread);
    //String que vai receber os valores gravados no buffer

    while ((resultado = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
        //Imprime o resultado
        System.out.println(resultado);

        js_object = new JSONObject(resultado);

    }
    //obj_kappauni1 = js_object.getJSONObject("kappauni1");
    // boolean alive = js_object.getBoolean("alive");
  //  System.out.println(alive);

    //Fecho gravação

    inStreamread.close();
    buffread.close();

}
}
```

Sempre que executo o código a cima, ele da o seguinte erro:

```
{
Exception in thread "main" classes_json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at classes_json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
    at classes_json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:220)
    at classes_json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:357)
    at Connection.conectar(Connection.java:33)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

O JSON que retorna é :

```
{
  "autopayout_from": "0.100", 
  "error": false, 
  "last_payment_amount": "0.10213405", 
  "last_payment_date": "Wed, 23 Aug 2017 03:57:19 GMT", 
  "last_share_date": "Sat, 26 Aug 2017 14:38:54 GMT", 
  "payout_daily": false, 
  "payout_request": false, 
  "total_hashrate": 205.15, 
  "total_hashrate_calculated": 211.58, 
  "wallet": "0x0940f5fAEF2bba7e1e6288E4bc4E9c75ee334b97", 
  "wallet_balance": "0.09611122", 
  "workers": {
    "kappauni1": {
      "alive": true, 
      "hashrate": 113.0, 
      "hashrate_below_threshold": false, 
      "hashrate_calculated": 140.58, 
      "last_submit": "Sat, 26 Aug 2017 14:38:54 GMT", 
      "second_since_submit": 149, 
      "worker": "kappauni1"
    }, 
    "kappauni2": {
      "alive": true, 
      "hashrate": 92.15, 
      "hashrate_below_threshold": false, 
      "hashrate_calculated": 71.0, 
      "last_submit": "Sat, 26 Aug 2017 14:38:20 GMT", 
      "second_since_submit": 183, 
      "worker": "kappauni2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve armazenar todo corpo da resposta HTTP em uma variável:

```
StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
    resultado.append(line).append('\n');
}
```

Após armazenar o corpo da resposta HTTP na variável `resultado`, você pode utilizar uma biblioteca para fazer a conversão. Uma forma simples é utilizando a biblioteca [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java). No seu caso, **depois** do `while`:

```
JSONObject jsonConvertido = new JSONObject(resultado.toString());
String valorJson = jsonConvertido.get("ChaveDoJson");
System.out.println(valorJson);
```

---

Se você quiser trabalhar com um JSON da mesma forma você trabalharia com um objeto Java, recomendo a utilização de bibliotecas mais robustas, como [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) ou [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi). Através da utilização delas, você pode criar classes Java que representam o JSON e a biblioteca se encarregará de fazer a conversão.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela luz, deu pra avançar mais um pouquinho, porém o problema agora é que ele retornar erro de syntax do JSON, e não sei o por que. Atualizei o código, se puder dar uma olhadinha e dizer conforme sua experiência :).

Comment: @DiegoKappaun atualizei a resposta com a parte de armazenar o corpo da resposta

Comment: Você leu a minha resposta e resolver editar a sua para colocar a resposta correta? Meio errado.

Comment: @Sorack 1 - se vc notar, minha resposta original já falava que ele deveria armazenar a resposta na variavel. Imaginei que ele conseguiria fazer sozinho. 2 - Se vc tbm notar, ele editou a pergunta dele DEPOIS que eu fiz uma sugestão. Sua resposta seria inválida sem a edição dele (e minha resposta). 3 - Sua resposta é ineficiente, já que usa concatenação de strings dentro de um loop. Abraço. =)

Comment: Muito obrigado, aprendi a fazer o procedimento, só estava um pouco sem tempo para vir até aqui. Agradeço a todos que me ajudaram :).

Answer (score 1):

O problema real é que você não estava lendo o `buffer` de resposta até o fim. Fiz também algumas melhorias no seu código para evitar que variáveis sejam criadas desnecessariamente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Connection {

  private static final String ENDERECO = "http://dwarfpool.com/eth/api?wallet=0940f5fAEF2bba7e1e6288E4bc4E9c75ee334b97";
  private JSONObject js_object;
  private JSONObject obj_kappauni1;

  private String conectar() throws IOException {
    URLConnection conexao;
    URL url;
    InputStreamReader is;
    String resultado;
    BufferedReader br;

    //Passo por parametro o endereco no qual deve pegar o json
    url = new URL(ENDERECO);
    //Abro conexão usando a url do json, assim vai ser conectado
    conexao = url.openConnection();
    //Ler valores da api
    is = new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream());
    //Guardar valores api em buffer
    br = new BufferedReader(is);
    //String que vai receber os valores gravados no buffer
    resultado = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    //obj_kappauni1 = js_object.getJSONObject("kappauni1");
    // boolean alive = js_object.getBoolean("alive");
    //  System.out.println(alive);

    //Fecho gravação
    is.close();
    br.close();

    return resultado;
  }
}
```